# How to search for Bluetooth devices?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I want to build an app that scan for local Bluetooth devices. The app finds all paired devices, but no unpaired device. I have a button and when I press it I want to see in the `Log` found devices.

In the `AndroidManifest` I added permissions for `BLUETOOTH`, `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` and `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`.

`onCreate` I get the default BluetoothAdapter and get the paired Devices.

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....
    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if(!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enable = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enable, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
    pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        ///Add paired Devices
        for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices){
            Log.i("DEVICE", device.getAddress()+" "+device.getName());
            devicesList.add(device);
        }
}
```

At `onClick` I do the `scanDevices` function where I use a `ScanCallBack`.

```
final ScanCallback scanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
       super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
       if(!devicesList.contains(result.getDevice())) {
          Log.i("DEVICE", result.getDevice().getName()+ "  "+result.getDevice().getAddress());
          devicesList.add(result.getDevice());
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
                super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
            }
        };

 bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().startScan(scanCallback);
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().stopScan(scanCallback);     
            }
        }, 10000);
}
```

When I start the app it doesn't do anything,no device printed in the Log, and when I try to debug it it doesn't even stop in the ScanCallBack.

Comment: Do you know why it doesn't find all devices at first scan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Android 6.0 / Marshmallow, any Bluetooth Scan requires the two following conditions:

1. Location permission (ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION is enough for now but not in [Android Q Beta apparently](https://www.cnx-software.com/2019/03/14/android-q-beta-preview-sdk/));
2. Location services being enabled and ON.

So this means that on any device running Android 6 or next, you must use the runtime permission request system to ask the user to grant you access to his location. But that is not enough, the user must also turn on his location service (precision is not a problem).

You can achieve that either by using Google Play services to show a popup requesting the user to turn on the location services or you can redirect to the location services in the Settings app where the user can toggle on his device location service.

As soon as both conditions are met, devices will start showing up in the logs if any are in range, of course.

Note: this is also valid for simple Bluetooth Discovery using Bluetooth Classic.

Comment: Do you know why it doesn't find all devices at first scan?

Comment: You're welcome! I guess for the first scan it's possible that, depending on the hardware, it can happen. Low Energy on Android has always be known to be unstable and with the variety of devices out there, it's no surprise.

Comment: I have one more question, do you know why it keeps disconnecting after just a few moments?

Comment: What do you mean disconnecting ? Do you mean you established a connection with an LE device and that connection gets closed after some time ?

Comment: Yes exactly that

Comment: Well, then, there can be many reasons and I don't have access to your code. Maybe the disconnection is initiated from the remote device. Maybe your Activity finishes, your Fragment gets detached etc...